# How to get rollup to use lambda instead of function in iife files

Tags: javascript, rollup

I'm new to JavaScript and using Rollup in my project. The IIFE file generated by Rollup looks like this:

```js
var jsstp=function(){/*things*/}()
```

I believe there is potential for word compression and we could change it to this:

```js
var jsstp = (() => {/*things*/})()
```

However, I haven't found any options in the Rollup documentation to do this. What should I do?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to convert from `function() {}` to a fat arrow function because a function defined using the `function` keyword has its own `this` context and a fat arrow function doesn't have it. Even if a function is not using its `this` context, it is hard to figure it out in a transpiler. If you want to have only arrow functions in your code, you could instead enforce that using a linter.